# HTML poetry tags

Tags: html, semantic-markup

There is a well known *paragraph* tag in HTML. Paragraph is a prose text element. When writing poetry we usually have strophes and versus (verse). There is any HTML tag for semantically representing poetry elements as strophes and versus? If not, there is plans for specifying it on future HTML specifications?

Comment: Not afaik, you probably better use some kind of css markup for that.

Comment: possibly useful: http://webdesignernotebook.com/css/styling-a-poem-with-advanced-css-selectors/

Comment: Surely I could, but CSS is for styling, not for semantics.

Comment: [this list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_html_dtd.asp) claims to show all available HTML Tags. As far as I can see, there is nothing that represents what you describe

Comment: @T3H40 This list is for HTML4. HTML5 is much more semantic.

Comment: @T3H40 No, you didn't. The first column says if that HTML4 tag is also presente in HTML5.